# Want image should be look good on any dimension screen...?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am working on mobile site and have a problem with image banner.

Example for tablet:

[image: screenshot-tablet]

But when i open website on mobile, it want to be like this:

[image: screenshot-mobile]

Here's my code so far

```
<div class="col-xs-12 topbar">
    <div class="row">
        <img src="img/bg.png" class="img-responsive" />
    </div>
</div>
```

The `height` should be fixed to `450px;`

How can I achieve this for mobile

Comment: make the width of the image div 100%; like this; `width:100%;`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your height.  If you remove the explicit height declaration then the image should scale to fit the containing element horizontally.  Of course, in doing so the height will be decreased because Bootstrap's `img-responsive` sets a height of `auto` to the image.

Or you could just doing it manually by removing the `img-responsive` class and adding `width: 100%` to the image.

In this case it'd look something like this:

**HTML**:

```html
<div class="row img-container">
    <img src="img/bg.png">
</div>
```

**CSS**:

```css
.img-container img {
    height: auto;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out the fiddle to crop the image & Try resizing the Result :-

http://jsfiddle.net/v94EA/

```
@media (max-width: 320px) {
#img_users {
    width: 150px;
    height: 450px;
    position: relative;
}
#img_users:before {
    content: '';    
    position: absolute;    
    z-index: -1;    
    background-image: url(http://1.bp.blogspot.com/_KRZSEI76J3c/TU_fMKDHnCI/AAAAAAAAD-   s/bbxZFyvTcf4/s400/Coastal_Holiday%252C_Sand_Beach.jpg); 
    background-position: center; 
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
}
```

Comment: Its compulsory to take 450px height & i just want to cut image or hide image form left & right side in low dimentions

Comment: You can apply one trick. Create a cropped image as per your need to be displayed in 320px devices & keep its display property to none & display that image by changing it display property to block. So, you will indeed have 2 images in your html. If you need code for this pls let me know.

Comment: Hi, I cant crop the images because the images will be added by users & its huge amount of images so i want it will be happen by code...

Answer (score 0):

## DEMO http://jsbin.com/eXOwICID/3/edit

### DEMO http://jsbin.com/eXOwICID/3/

```
  <div class="banner-wrapper">
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/g/768/450" class="img-responsive img-banner center-block" />
  </div>
```

CSS

```
@media (max-width:320px) {

 .img-responsive.img-banner {
   max-width:none!important;
   position:absolute;
   top:0;
   left:-25%;
   max-height:275px;
 }
  .banner-wrapper {
    position:relative;
    overflow:hidden;
    max-height:275px;
    width:100%;
    height:275px;
 }

}
```

I'm just making a guess on the size of the original image and the left position. You'll have to play around with this.